# How to stage data using VS 2010 Unit Test Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I'm setting up some unit tests in VS 2010 using .Net 4.0 using the test project and the `[TestMethod]` decorations.  Some of my tests require some data to be staged in the database prior running.

I created a method called `StageUserStoreData()` which does this.  How can I make the method run prior to running any of the tests?  Ideally, I would only like this method called once, that is once the data is staged, I do not need to call it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three kinds of initialization methods, and they run in the following order:

- Method marked with [`[AssemblyInitialize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx) runs before **any tests in the assembly**.
  (Note that it still has to be inside a `[TestClass]`)
- Method marked with [`[ClassInitialize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx) runs before **any tests in the class**.
- Method marked with[`[TestInitialize]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx) runs before **each test**.

Comment: I used AssemblyInitialize and that worked great.  Thx for your answer.